# postgres: how to improve update performance for un-indexed columns?

Tags: postgresql

In my PostgreSQL 9.3 database I have a table "my_table", which has 5 columns:

col1, col2, col3, col4, and col5

The first two columns (col1 and col2) are included into a unique index, but the other 3 columns do not have any indexes on them.

This table is being used with a 3-rd party utility, which performs updates in the following way:

```
"update my_table set col3 = "some value"

where col1 = ...

and col2 = ...

and col3 = ...

and col4 = ...

and col5 = ..."
```

These updates run extremely slow, but I do not have ability to modify this auto-generated SQL.

I can only make changes to the table "my_table".

What is the best thing I could do, to accommodate this type of update query and increase its performance?

Comment: If the table has a unique index (col1, col2) then the other tree conditions practically does not matter to the total execution time, so there's not much you can do with it.

Comment: Note: 'some value' should be in single quotes, double quotes are for identifiers. BTW: a table without a primary key (or candidate key) is essentially meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested the situation you described. As klin stated, the database initially uses the unique index, and it's pretty fast. But if you create a non-unique index, covering all searched columns (col1 to col5), this index will be favored. Tested on 2 million rows, first 2 columns are random IDs, rest are low-dispersion values.

So if you are not afraid of a larger index, consider adding one that will cover all searched columns.